# Is it possible with MySQL to generate a query to fetch from several tables even if one has no results?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm facing a problem here:

I'm building a forum, this forum has several tables and I'm trying to fetch the comments and user info in a single query.

So far, it should be easy, the problem is that I can't change the structure and with the following query I get a perfect result IF there is a like to the answer. If no one likes the answer it fails.

```
Select
  mfr.mfr_forum_answers.id,
  mfr.mfr_forum_answers.date_created,
  mfr.mfr_forum_answers.last_updated,
  mfr.mfr_forum_answers.content,
  mfr.mfr_forum_answers.accepted,
  mfr.mfr_forum_answers.user_id,
  mfr.mfr_users.level,
  mfr.mfr_users.avatar,
  mfr.mfr_forum_likes.subject_id,
  mfr.wp_users.ID As ID1,
  mfr.mfr_forum_topics.user_id As owner_id,
  (SELECT count(mfr.mfr_forum_likes.id) FROM mfr.mfr_forum_likes WHERE mfr.mfr_forum_likes.subject_id = :id AND mfr.mfr_forum_likes.type = 'answer') as likes,
  (SELECT count(mfr.mfr_forum_likes.id) FROM mfr.mfr_forum_likes WHERE mfr.mfr_forum_likes.subject_id = :id AND makefitreal.mfr_forum_likes.type = 'answer' AND mfr.mfr_forum_likes.user_id = :sessionId ) as i_like,
 mfr.wp_users.user_nicename
From
  mfr.mfr_forum_likes Inner Join
  mfr.mfr_forum_answers
    On mfr.mfr_forum_answers.topic_id =
    mfr.mfr_forum_likes.subject_id Inner Join
  mfr.mfr_users
    On mfr.mfr_forum_answers.user_id = mfr.mfr_users.id
  Inner Join
  mfr.wp_users
    On mfr.mfr_users.id = mfr.wp_users.ID Inner Join
  mfr.mfr_forum_topics
    On mfr.mfr_forum_answers.topic_id = mfr.mfr_forum_topics.id
Where
     mfr.mfr_forum_answers.topic_id = :id
And
     mfr.mfr_forum_likes.type = 'answer'
```

So far as said it returns only if an answer has a like, I'm thinking on adding a add to the user who posts the answer by default but I'm trying to improve my skills by solving new issues.

If someone has a suggestion in how I could overcome the fact that if a table is empty, the query continues I'd be really thankfull.

Thanks in advance-

Pihh

Comment: Please comment why the downvote. It's hard for me to don't repeat the mistake if I can't understand what's wrong:

PS: I had the exact answer I wanted so it must be clear to who understands this subject, I did research stackoverflow but didn't find any satisfatory explanations, so I'm not seeing why the downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. What you are looking for are called [left and right joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html). According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html), with a `LEFT JOIN` you still join two tables as normal but

> If there is no matching row for the right table in the ON or USING part in a LEFT JOIN, a row with all columns set to NULL is used for the right table.

This means that you can *try* to join two tables, but if a row does not have any results it will still return the results from the first table. The same is true for a `RIGHT JOIN` only it works the opposite way: it will return results if the tabled being *joined to* has results, but the original table does not.

It looks like you have 3 tables for 3 relationships: there are answers, a user gives an answer, and an answer *might or might not* have like. To grab this data, I would suggest starting from your `answers` table, performing an `INNER JOIN` on your `users` table (assuming there are always users), and a `LEFT JOIN` on your `likes` table. Here is a simple example:

```
SELECT *
FROM answers
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = answers.user_id
LEFT JOIN likes ON likes.answer_id = answer.id
WHERE answers.id = :id
AND likes.type = 'answers'
```

Of course, if for some unknown reason you need to start from your `likes` table, then you'd have to `RIGHT JOIN` the other tables. I hope that gives you a good idea of how you'd make your query.

Comment: Andy, I just learned something new today with you. Many thanks. Previously I've used left and right joins just for the sake of filtering data but didn't ever get that detail.

Thanks for this tip, if I could I'd upvote you twice